# Writing a Qt app on a tablet

Tags: android, qt

I am thinking of developing an application for Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (or perhaps some other tablet). I would like to use c++ with qt on windows 7 to write the app. Would the app be compatible with this tablet? I don't have any experience when to comes to writing apps for tables so any advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As with all other Qt applications you will need to build it for the specific platform. This can be done using Qt Creator. Download the Necessitas project and other needed SDKs and build them.

To test the application Qt Creator provides emulators, but you will need to test on real devices in order to ship the application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible, see [Necessitas](http://sourceforge.net/p/necessitas/home/necessitas/) project.